# How can I use Arquillian without Maven?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss-arquillian

I'm making my first Java EE project and can't figure how to test my EJB. I've read that Arquillian is really useful to do integration tests, but it seems like using it without Maven is difficult. Could someone tell me if there is a way to use it or a tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using any sort of dependency management tool, eg Ivy? I really recommend using one, since it makes things much easier.

That said, Arquillian does not use Maven itself, so you can use it without Maven. You will just have to figure out which dependencies you need. You can either work it out by just looking at the Maven POM files, or you could start with a sample Maven based setup and use the maven-dependency-plugin to export the libraries you need. See also https://gist.github.com/mojavelinux/2363038.

Personally I would recommend to just use a dependency management tool, be it Maven or Ivy.

Comment: Thanks @Hardy, I will try to use Maven, I didn't want to because I already had a Java EE project but it seems the better option.